# Python - Is there a way to append multiple values to one key?

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I have a list of numbers and values for each number. What I want to do is check if the number  already exists in a dictionary and if it does, append the value to that list of values for the specific key.

For an Example

```
0  
a   

2
b

3
c

0
d

7
e
```

What I want to achieve is to populate a dictionary where the numbers would be the keys and letters would be the values.However in the event that the number 0 comes up again I want to take the value of the second 0 and append it to my list of values.

Basically the outcome would be

```
 "0" : [a,d]
 "2" : [b]
 "3" : [c]
 "7" : [e]
```

Right now im in the process of the following:

```
num_letter_dict = {}
num = ['0', '2', '3', '0','7']
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e']

for line in num:
    if line in num_letter_dict:
        num_letter_dict[line].append(letters)
    else:
        num_letter_dict[line] = [letters]

    print(num_letter_dict)
```

This is the result I am getting

```
{'0': [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']]}
{'0': [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']], '2': [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']]}
{'0': [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']], '2': [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']]}
{'0': [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']], '2': [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']], '3': [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']]}
{'0': [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']], '2': [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']], '3': [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']], '7': [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']]}
```

Comment: You can use a collections.defaultdict with a list parameter instead of a regular dict.

Comment: I can't see in what sense `'0'` is associated with `'d'` in the input lists shown in your code. Have values got swapped?

Comment: Why do you append the whole list of letters instead of a single letter? Add some index and you will achieve exactly what you wanted.

Comment: @alaniwi I fixed the values  they were swapped

Comment: @Malcode Thanks for confirming.

Comment: if you are reading from a file, this snippet might help you - https://repl.it/@marmeladze1/SwelteringAmbitiousLoopfusion#main.py

Answer (score 0):

You're appending `letters`, which by itself is a full list. Instead, you want to append the element in `letter` that corresponds to the index of the key you're looking at in the `num` list.

```
for idx, line in enumerate(num):
    if line in num_letter_dict:
        num_letter_dict[line].append(letters[idx]) # append the element
    else:
        num_letter_dict[line] = [letters[idx]]
```

Result:

```
>>> print(num_letter_dict)
{'0': ['a', 'c'], '2': ['b'], '3': ['d'], '7': ['e']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to append the individual letter to the relevant list inside the dictionary, and not the whole list of letters.  The `zip` function will loop over corresponding values from the two input lists as shown:

```
num_letter_dict = {}
num = ['0', '2', '3', '0','7']
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e']

for n, letter in zip(num, letters):
    if n not in num_letter_dict:
        num_letter_dict[n] = []
    num_letter_dict[n].append(letter)
print(num_letter_dict)
```

Gives:

```
{'0': ['a', 'c'], '3': ['d'], '7': ['e'], '2': ['b']}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you.

```
num_letter_dict = {}
num = ['0', '2', '0', '3','7']
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e']

for value, line in zip(letters,num):
    if line in num_letter_dict:
        num_letter_dict[line].append(value) # append the element
    else:
        num_letter_dict[line] = [value]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, I have modified the `for` loop and used `extend`

```py
for i, letter in zip(num, letters):
    if i not in num_letter_dict:
        num_letter_dict[i] = []
    num_letter_dict[i].extend(letter) #change over here
print(num_letter_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, I had to deal with this same issue yesterday. While the other submitted answers would work, might I recommend the [`defaultdict` from the Collections module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict)?

```py
from collections import defaultdict

num = ['0', '2', '3', '0','7']
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e']

num_letter_dict = defaultdict(list)
for n, letter in zip(num, letters):
    num_letter_dict[n].append(letter)

print(num_letter_dict)
```

I like this approach because it allows the `defaultdict` class to do the construction of the list internally, rather than muddying up one's own source code with if-statements.

You can test-execute this solution on IDEOne: https://ideone.com/9Dg9Rk